# Aws lambda not connecting with Dynamo Db

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda

I am getting this error when i am trying to trigger

> There was an error creating the trigger: Cannot access stream
>   arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-2:xxxxxx:table/xxxx/stream/2017-09-18T07:47:01.834.
>   Please ensure the role can perform the GetRecords, GetShardIterator,
>   DescribeStream, and ListStreams Actions on your stream in IAM.

Please help me,

Answer (score 22):

When attaching a trigger to a DynamoDb table, you will get the error as posted by OP

You need to add a policy to the IAM role generated for that lambda function.

Here is sample JSON you can use to create the policy, just replace the lambda function and stream ARNs.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "lambda:InvokeFunction",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:region:accountnumber:function:functionname"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "dynamodb:DescribeStream",
                "dynamodb:GetRecords",
                "dynamodb:GetShardIterator",
                "dynamodb:ListStreams"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:dynamodb:region:accountnumber:table/table-name/stream/2019-02-27T07:41:49.893"
        }
    ]
}
```

Once you create the policy and attach it to the role, you can then go back to DynamoDB and create a new trigger with the lambda function. If done correctly, it will create without errors.

Comment: Can you take a look here please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70016674/invalidparametervalueexception-cannot-access-stream

Comment: If you're using SAM template. You can one line this with: DynamoDBStreamReadPolicy

Answer (score 3):

As per error message, your IAM settings are not correct. You need to assign these kinds of Roles to your user.

You will have to create a policy that allows your AWS functions to access Cloudwatch logs as well as the table you just created. Go to the IAM console, select 'Roles' and then 'Create new role'.

[image]

Select the 'AWS Lambda' role:
[image]

And then click 'Next step' to skip the 'Attach Policy' section

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_create_for-user.html will help you to tackle with this error.
[image]
Also, I tried to follow information from: https://github.com/dwyl/learn-aws-lambda#what-is-lambda for accessing dynamodb and it's working fine with root(main) user.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you only need to create this role with policy **AWSLambdaDynamoDBExecutionRole**  and attach to your lambda. You probably don't want full access as this is a read action.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

When you create a lambda function, Lambda create a role by default for the lambda function created, but that role isn't enough to give permissions to Dynamo to invoke lambda functions. So in role seccion seek your lambda function and attach the  AWSLambdaInvocation-DynamoDB policy.

Answer (score 0):

Attach `AWSLambdaKinesisExecutionRole` policy to the lambda function. This policy is pre defined by AWS. You can just use that in your lambda SAM template.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).